# PySpark out of Java heap space even after increasing spark.driver.memory

Tags: apache-spark, memory, pyspark, heap-memory

I have tried increasing memory by increasing spark.driver.memory but still getting out of memory error.
Do i need to go garbage collection?

i am calling these function one after other to do the transformations but keep getting :

PySpark: java.lang.OutofMemoryError: Java heap space

i have checked old questions but they where  not helpful.

I dont have the logs but hear is the code which is causing the problem.

```
df.toPandas().to_csv('out.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a system variable:

`_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4G -Xms3G.`

As by default this variable might be set to smaller value . if you have 8GB ram this much should solve your problem.